# A question from an olympiad handout on polynomials and algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

Let $$P(n) =  \frac{n^2-8n+36}{n^2+8n+36}$$
be a prime number for a real number $n$. Find the sum of all $P(n)$.

I found out n has to be negative and found one such value at $n=-6$ , at which $P(n)$ is equal to $5$. Are there any other values of other $n$ ?

Comment: sorry wanted to write n = -6

Comment: You wrote "for real number n" - are you sure? Then try $n=6(\sqrt{3}-2)$.

Comment: how did you get that value

Comment: I just solved $P(n)=2$. This is a quadratic equation - very easy. The second solution is $n=-6(\sqrt{3}+2)$. I can do this for every prime.

Comment: i also tried this method , i am finding that  values of P(n) , where n is greater than 7 and prime , the roots are complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve the quadratic equation $P(n)=p$ for $n$.
It is given by
$$
 n^2(1-p) - 8np - 8n - 36p + 36=0.
$$
The solutions are
$$
n=\frac{2(\pm \sqrt{- 5p^2 + 26p - 5} - 2p - 2)}{p-1}
$$
We need that $- 5p^2 + 26p - 5\ge 0$, which means $p\le 5$.
So this implies $p=2$, or $p=3$, or $p=5$. Now we  compute $P(n)$ for these three cases and sum up.

Comment: Also writing $\frac{n^2-8n+36}{n^2+8n+36}=1-\frac{16n}{n^2+8n+36} =1-p$ can reduce some computations .

Comment: @lonestudent I thought the fraction $P(n)$ equals $p$ and not $1-p$.

Comment: But, my point was slightly different. I mean, writing $\frac {16n}{n^2+8n+36}=p$ and finding $\Delta_n$ requires less computation .

Comment: @lonestudent My point is only that you wrote $\frac{n^2-8n+36}{n^2+8n+36}=1-p$, which is wrong (or confusing given the notation of my answer). It should be $\frac{n^2-8n+36}{n^2+8n+36}=p$.

Comment: I write $\frac {16n}{n^2+8n+36}=p ~\text{or}~ =q$ *not* $\frac {16n}{n^2+8n+36}=P(n)$ this yields $\Delta_n≥0 \implies  P(n)≤5$ .